# Insert item into database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having issues inserting this into my database I think tis when I try to convert my prdocutPrice string or stock string into decimal and int values. I am pretty certain I am doing the rest right can someone confirm for me?

```
<?php 

    if (isset($_POST['addSubmitted'])) {

        $errors = array();
        require_once ('mysql_connect.php');

            //This gets all the other information from the form 
            $name=$_POST['productName']; 
            $description=$_POST['productDescription']; 
            $price= floatval($_POST['productPrice']); 
            $stock= intval($_POST['productStock']);


        if (empty($errors)) {
            //Writes the information to the database 
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (name, description, price, stock) VALUES ($name, $description, $price, $stock)"); 
            $result = mysql_query($query);

            if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) {
                // Show thank you message
                echo '<span style="color:green;">Your product has been added.</span>';
            } else {
                echo '<font color="red">We were unable to add your product to the database.</font>';
            }

        } else {
            echo '<font color="red"><h3>Error!</h3>
            The following error(s) occured:<br /></font>';

            foreach ($errors as $msg) {
                echo " - <font color=\"red\">$msg</font><br />\n";
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of your string values are correctly quoted in the `INSERT` statement. Surround them in single quotes.

Also, first thing's first -- be sure to call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on all the string input values, as they are currently vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['productName']); 
$description= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['productDescription']); 
$price= floatval($_POST['productPrice']); 
$stock= intval($_POST['productStock']);
```

Further, you are calling `mysql_query()` twice instead of storing the SQL string into your variable `$query`.

```
// Quote the string values,
// store the SQL as a variable then pass it to mysql_query()
$query = "INSERT INTO products (name, description, price, stock) VALUES ('$name', '$description', $price, $stock)"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

A call to `echo mysql_error();` would have helped to debug the problems with your SQL statement.

Finally, one more note I'll add - in addition to calling `intval()` or `floatval()` on strings passed from `$_POST`, it is usually a good idea to verify that the numbers are actually *numbers*.  Otherwise if they are non numeric values, they will be cast to 0 and you'll get zeros in your database when you probably shouldn't have inserted it at all (since it is invalid data).

```
if (is_numeric($_POST['productPrice'])) {
   $price = floatval($_POST['productPrice']);
}
else // non numeric value, don't do the insert with bad data
```

For positive or zero integers, I like to use [`ctype_digit()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php):

```
if (ctype_digit($_POST['productStock'])) {
  $stock = intval($_POST['productStock']);
}
else // bad input value, don't do insert
```

Comment: ooo mysql_error() thats handy! thanks for taking your time to give me such a great answer!

Comment: at the end of the $query you have an extra ')'

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, I believe you need quotes around the values (especially strings):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (name, description, price, stock) VALUES ('$name', '$description', '$price', '$stock')");
```

But you also need to escape your variables using `mysql_real_escape_string` or switch to something like [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1):

1) You're vulnerable to SQL injection. Read through http://bobby-tables.com BEFORE you continue on with any of your code
2) You've neglected quotes in your queries, causing syntax errors. You also have no error handling whatsoever, and assume your queries succeeded:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (name, description, price, stock) VALUES ('$name', '$description', etc....) 
                                                                            ^     ^
```

note the additional quotes. As for the error handling, the absolutely bare minimum you should ALWAYS use is

```
 $result = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());
```

Even if your query string is absolutely perfectly valid (and yours definitely isn't), there's far too many other reasons for a query to fail to **NOT** check for success/failure.

Answer (score 0):

if (empty($errors)) {
        //Writes the information to the database 
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (name, description, price, stock) VALUES ($name, $description, $price, $stock)"); 
        $result = mysql_query($query);

should this not be:

if (empty($errors)) {
        //Writes the information to the database 
        **$query= "INSERT INTO products (name, description, price, stock) VALUES ($name, $description, $price, $stock";** 
        $result = mysql_query($query);

Answer (score 0):

> mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (name, description, price, stock) VALUES ($name, $description, $price, $stock)");

You didn't declare the variable for your mysql_query. Also, Michael had some good points about escaping the string values.
Try this with the **$query** variable and single quotes around the values.

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (name, description, price, stock) VALUES ('$name', '$description', '$price', '$stock')");
```